# Use Like functionality for in SharePoint 2013 to add and display list item on page

Tags: list, jsom, like

I have the list called comments, I'm displaying those comments list item on page using JSOM.
Now I have enabled likes for the list

I'm trying to use like list item functionally on a page to like particular comments list item. 
Also, I have to show all list item likes on page also

Comment: Is server side code is OK for you? We have implemented same functionality using data service class which is called by ajax and updating item using Reputation OOTB class. I'll provide you with sample if this is OK for you, Andrew.

Answer (score 0):

We have achieved this using server side list item update using OOTB `Reputation` class from **Microsoft.Office.Server.ReputationModel**.

To do this:

1. In _layouts ("Layouts" mapped folder) create new application page
   which will serve AJAX methods.
2. Create method "LikeItem"

This method will be called from AJAX to execute server side logic:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = false)]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static bool LikeItem(string itemId)
{
   try
   {
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(itemId)) return false;

      int item;
      var isIdPassed = int.TryParse(itemId, out item);

      if (!isIdPassed) return false;

      // Get list to like item in
      var list = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.Lists.TryGetList(<List title>);

      // Set
      Reputation.SetLike(list.ID.ToString(), item, true);

      return true;
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      return false;
   }
}
```

From JS call the method:

```
var executeOptions = {
   type: "POST",
   url: "/_layouts/DataService.aspx/LikeItem",
   data: "{itemId: '" + <id of the item> + "' }",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: "json",
   headers: {
      "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
   },
   xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }
};

$.ajax(executeOptions).then(function (content) {
   if (!content.d) {
      // Handle errors here
   }

   // success - do your logic here
});
```

Hope this helps,

Andrew